# Redis expiry notification matching a specific key pattern

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, spring-data

Is there a way to implement a key expiry logic matching a specific pattern in Redis with Spring?

Here is what I have accomplished until now.

```
RedisMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer = new RedisMessageListenerContainer();
listenerContainer.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
listenerContainer.setErrorHandler(new ExpirationListenerErrorHandler());
listenerContainer.addMessageListener(keyExpiredListener, new PatternTopic("__key*__:ex*"));
```

I am now wondering if I can play a little bit with `__key*__:ex*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked.

```
RedisMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer = new RedisMessageListenerContainer();
listenerContainer.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
listenerContainer.setErrorHandler(new ExpirationListenerErrorHandler());
listenerContainer.addMessageListener(keyExpiredListener,
            new PatternTopic("__keyspace@*:example_*");
return listenerContainer;
```

Where `"example_*"` is a pattern that matches keys that start with `"example"`

**Important**: You have to enable key space notifications through Redis cli

`redis-cli config set notify-keyspace-events Kx`